# How to detect javascript version conformance using javascript

Tags: javascript, version

Is there a way to detect which version of javascript this engine has? on console and browsers

for example i want to know conformance of

```
/usr/bin/js
/usr/bin/node
/usr/bin/ringo
/usr/bin/rhino
/usr/bin/seed
/usr/bin/gjs 
and browsers i currently using, etc
```

are they Javascript 1.8.5 compatible or not, or which version of javascript they had

Answer (score 1):

Check the following similar scenario.Hope this helps

[jQuery version compatibility detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655308/jquery-version-compatibility-detection/3113707#3113707)

Thanks
AB

Comment: That answer is for **jQuery**, not javascript. The linked answer uses the jQuery version property (intuitively called "jquery"), there is no equivalent in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try the  following script to know the Javascript version

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsver = 1.0;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.1">
  jsver = 1.1;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.2">
  jsver = 1.2;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.3">
  jsver = 1.3;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.4">
  jsver = 1.4;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.5">
  jsver = 1.5;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.6">
  jsver = 1.6;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.7">
  jsver = 1.7;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.8">
  jsver = 1.8;
</script>
<script language="Javascript1.9">
  jsver = 1.9;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jsver);
</script>
```

Check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ac6CT/

Thanks

AB