# Determining Versions of jQuery with WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How do I determine the versions of jQuery that shipped with each version of WordPress since like version 2.7? Was there a log kept somewhere on this? Because as a plugin developer, I may need to rely on a function that might not work in older versions of WordPress.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073423/jquery-plugin-check-version

Comment: No, not exactly. Am looking simply for a chart where someone may have recorded which versions of WP come with which versions of jQuery already -- a shortcut to having to download like 8 installs of old WP and doing my own tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good table can be queried from the [Core Track](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/query?type=enhancement&component=External+Libraries&summary=~jquery&col=id&col=summary&col=type&col=milestone&col=time&order=id):

[image: 30 results, from jquery 1.5.2 to 1.10.4]

Answer (score 5):

You can [query the version of jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-check-jquery-version.html):

> ```
> // Returns string Ex: "1.3.1"
> $().jquery;
>
> // Also returns string Ex: "1.3.1"
> jQuery.fn.jquery;
> ```

Comment: Well, yeah, but was looking for a chart where hopefully someone already recorded this. Perhaps there is not a chart out there?