# Sorting by numbers as String - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-orderby

I would like to sort a table by 'numbers'. Those 'numbers' represent version-numbers of applications or dependencies of those. They look like "2.11.7" or "6.41.6". Because of that, i can't convert them into numbers. But when handling them like a String, angulars orderBy sorts them not properly. To be more specific:

- 2.11.5
- 2.11.5
- 2.11.7
- 2.11.7
- 2.11.5

will end up in (DESC)

- 2.11.7
- 2.11.7
- 2.11.5
- 2.11.5
- 2.11.7

or (ASC)

- 2.11.7
- 2.11.5
- 2.11.7
- 2.11.7
- 2.11.5

Now i got stuck. Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting can be accomplished by plain javascript. Here is an example adapted from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201533/sort-version-dotted-number-strings-in-javascript) for sorting of versions

As far as AngularJs is concerned, the [order by also allows for a custom comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) to be provided. Here they have an example with a custom comparator to sort the values. All it requires is to use a function similar to the one above (or your own logic) to provide for a custom comparator. The flag for sorting direction can be provided via the expression itself by passing true/false.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/v9D8AIrqxEXF8MdDxJc4?p=preview) edited from their own example to provide for your values. Feel free to play around. This example will run properly in [the Plunker environment](https://plnkr.co/edit/v9D8AIrqxEXF8MdDxJc4?p=preview). The code is listed here for documentation

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('orderByExample4', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.friends = [
                { name: 'John', favoriteLetter: '2.11.5' },
                { name: 'Mary', favoriteLetter: '2.11.5' },
                { name: 'Mike', favoriteLetter: '2.11.7' },
                { name: 'Adam', favoriteLetter: '2.11.7' },
                { name: 'Julie', favoriteLetter: '2.11.5' }
    ];

            function pad(version) {
                var paddingString = "0000000000";
                return version
                    .split('.')
                    .map(function(majorMinorVersion) {
                        var index = paddingString.length - majorMinorVersion.length;
                        return paddingString.substr(0, index) + majorMinorVersion;
                    })
                    .join('.');
            }

            $scope.localeSensitiveComparator = function(v1, v2) {
                // If we don't get strings, just compare by index
                if (v1.type !== 'string' || v2.type !== 'string') {
                    return (v1.index < v2.index) ? -1 : 1;
                }

                var a = pad(v1.value);
                var b = pad(v2.value);
                return a.localeCompare(b);
            };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```