# Unable to sort array of objects by version number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects in that I want to sort the array based on the `xxx` version number string. But it seems there is an issue in sorting the order as per my desire.

I have seen the existing solutions for example, the [Existing Question Suggested by community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201533/sort-version-dotted-number-strings-in-javascript). But it dealt with plain arrays instead of array of objects. I can tweak the answer as per needs. But the solutions seems to be pretty long. So I'm looking for a much simpler solutions.

**Example Object:**

```
my_list = [{"xxx": "9.6", "no_of_occurrence": 1 }, {"xxx": "9.2", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
{"xxx": "9.11", "no_of_occurrence": 1}, {"xxx": "9.10", "no_of_occurrence": 1}]
```

After sorting My desired output should be

**Either**

```
[{"xxx": "9.11", "no_of_occurrence": 1 }, {"xxx": "9.10", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
{"xxx": "9.6", "no_of_occurrence": 1}, {"xxx": "9.2", "no_of_occurrence": 1}]
```

**or**

```
[{"xxx": "9.2", "no_of_occurrence": 1 }, {"xxx": "9.6", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
{"xxx": "9.10", "no_of_occurrence": 1}, {"xxx": "9.11", "no_of_occurrence": 1}]
```

To achieve this I'm facing some issues. The decimal places are not treated the way they should be.

What I've tried so far is:

**Approach 1:**

```
my_list.sort((a, b) => 
     {
       if (a['xxx'] < b['xxx']) {
         return -1;
       }
       if (a['xxx'] > b['xxx']) {
         return 1;
       }
       return 0;
     }
  );
```

**Approach 2:**

```
my_list.sort((a, b) => {a['xxx'] - b['xxx']});
```

I did tried converting the string to float by using the "parseFloat(a['xxx'])" and "parseFloat(a['xxx']).toFixed(2)" as well. But nothing seems to be working.

The output generated by the above sort functions is:

```
[{
 no_of_occurrence: 1,
 xxx: "9.6"
}, {
 no_of_occurrence: 1,
 xxx: "9.2"
}, {
 no_of_occurrence: 1,
 xxx: "9.11"
}, {
 no_of_occurrence: 1,
 xxx: "9.10"
}]
```

However I tried, I'm not able to achieve what I desired. How can I treat the 9.10 is greater than 9.2? I know javascript treats 9.10 as 9.1 vise versa. But the data I received from the client and the client expectation is 9.10 is > 9.2.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: This answer on [how to sort version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40201533/3297291) might help

Comment: Are these regular floating point numbers (where 9.6 > 9.11) or are they version numbers (where 9.11 > 9.6)? Your desired ordering suggests the latter.

Comment: @jarmod: These are version numbers. That means 9.10 is greater than 9.6

Comment: That's critical context. I've modified the question to clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort version-dotted number strings in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201533/sort-version-dotted-number-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the link @jarmod. This link is same as the one provided by the user3297291. This could solve my problem. But the answers in this thread dealt with simple array of elements. I can extend the answer to cater my need. But fortunately I got the solution I'm looking for from the community of great minds here. Once again thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or simply do this:

```js
const my_list = [{"xxx": "9.6", "no_of_occurrence": 1 }, {"xxx": "9.2", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
{"xxx": "9.11", "no_of_occurrence": 1}, {"xxx": "9.10", "no_of_occurrence": 1}];

console.log(my_list.sort((a,b)=>{a=a.xxx.split(".");b=b.xxx.split(".");
 return a[0]-b[0] || a[1]-b[1];}));
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I treat the 9.10 is greater than 9.2?

Here you are not considering them as regular floating values. So if you ignore the `.`, you can easily compare them.

Try this one

```
my_list.sort((a, b) => {
       const _a = a['xxx'].split('.')
       const _b = b['xxx'].split('.')
       if (Number(_a[0]) < Number(_b[0])) {
         return -1;
       }
       if (Number(_a[0]) > Number(_b[0])) {
         return 1;
       }
       if (Number(_a[1]) < Number(_b[1])) {
          return -1;
       }
       if (Number(_a[1]) > Number(_b[1])) {
          return 1;
       }
       return 0;
     });
```

Comment: It will not work for i.e. 10.6

Comment: Yes. It is failing for a lot of other numbers. Thanks for the quick response. I hope the sorting is performing on the decimal numbers rather than the actual numbers.

Comment: @libik Thanks for the correction. Hope my last edit will work.

Answer (score 2):

The Prana solution was close, but it is not sufficient one. Based on the order you are not comparing float, because `9.10 < 9.11 < 9.2 < 9.6`, but that is not order you want.

Its more like chapters and subchapters, then you need to compare the chapter part first, and subchapter part later.

```js
const my_list = [{"xxx": "10.6", "no_of_occurrence": 1 }, {"xxx": "9.2", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
{"xxx": "9.11", "no_of_occurrence": 1}, {"xxx": "9.10", "no_of_occurrence": 1}]

const sorted = my_list.sort((a, b) => {
       const _a = Number(a['xxx'].split('.')[0])
       const _b = Number(b['xxx'].split('.')[0])
       if (_a < _b) {
         return -1;
       }
       if (_a > _b) {
         return 1;
       }
       
       const _aa = Number(a['xxx'].split('.')[1])
       const _bb = Number(b['xxx'].split('.')[1])

       if (_aa < _bb) {
         return -1;
       }
       if (_aa > _bb) {
         return 1;
       }

       return 0;
     });
     
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks @liblik. This worked. It worked even for the numbers like ".31" and "15" as well.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal values are being treathened the way they should be. Floating point numbers are not the same as version numbers, so it's true that 9.10 is not > 9.2.

But I see what you want to achieve: You want to sort them numbers as if they where version numbers. To achieve your goal, you need to write an own sort algorithm something like this:

```
my_list.sort(function(a,b){
    var a1 = a['xxx'].split('.');
    var b1 = b['xxx'].split('.');
    var len = Math.max(a1.length, b1.length);

    for(var i = 0; i< len; i++){
        var _a = +a1[i] || 0;
        var _b = +b1[i] || 0;
        if(_a === _b) continue;
        else return _a > _b ? 1 : -1
    }
    return 0;
})
```

This will give you a result such as:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and solution. It worked for all the scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic solution

```js
let my_list = [
  {"xxx": "9.6", "no_of_occurrence": 1 },
  {"xxx": "9.2", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
  {"xxx": "9.11.3", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
  {"xxx": "9.11.1", "no_of_occurrence": 1},
  {"xxx": "9.10", "no_of_occurrence": 1}
];

my_list.sort((a, b) => {
    let va = a.xxx.split("."), vb = b.xxx.split("."), i = 0
    while(i < va.length && i < vb.length && (+va[i]) == (+vb[i]))
        i++;
    return (+va[i]) - (+vb[i]);
})

console.log(my_list)
```