# jQuery sort integer with leading 0 in decimal

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm Using [Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/) to show some data.
Now the data should be sorted by it's position and the position of it's category.

For example

- Category position 1 and entry position 1 = 1.1
- Category position 1 and entry position 2 = 1.2
- Category position 1 and entry position 3 = 1.3
- Category position 1 and entry position 10 = 1.10

now I get the wrong sort:

1.1

1.10

1.2

1.3

When I use **parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)** I get 1.10, 1.10, 1.20,...

It's also wrong. Got anyone an idea, how to manage this issue?

1.10 should be the last one in the row.

Comment: 1.1 === 1.10...

Comment: You need to split at point and compare the first and second values by themselves.

Comment: maybe you should treat them like versions, try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7717160/1595977 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number