# How to sort HTML Table in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, reactstrap

I have `array` of `Objects` and I add my data to `HTML Table`. Now I need to sort my data by version. How can I do something like that in `React`?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Label> We got {this.state.count} elements in our database. </Label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Table hover striped bordered responsive size="sm" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>VERSION</th>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>UUID</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.results.map(result =>
                <tr key={result.fileId}>
                  <td>{result.VERSION}</td>
                  <td>{result.ORIGIN}</td>
                  <td>{result.UUID}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe I can use some `js` script, but tell me how to use it, I'm new with `ReactJS`. My version for is `0.26.8` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use lodash's `sortBy()` function here:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

```
const sorted = _.sortBy(this.state.results, 'VERSION')
```

Then map over `sorted` instead of the `this.state.results`

Answer (score 2):

Simply **make sure `this.state.results` is sorted** correctly before rendering.

---

The simplest approach would likely be similar to the following:

```
  {this.state.results.sort((a, b) => a.VERSION - b.VERSION).map(result =>
    <tr key={result.fileId}>
      <td>{result.VERSION}</td>
      <td>{result.ORIGIN}</td>
      <td>{result.UUID}</td>
    </tr>
  )}
```

---

**Edit:** Since you stated that the version is not a numeric value, but rather a [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) string, your sort function needs to be a bit more complex. I suggest you have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717109/how-can-i-compare-arbitrary-version-numbers), or use [one of the many available libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=js%20compare%20semver) covering that use case.

Comment: My version looks like: `0.22.6`, not only one number. I forgot to add it to description. Already updated, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
const sorted = results.sort((x,y) => {
    return parseInt(x.VERSION) - parseInt(y.VERSION);
});
```

sorts in Ascending order

Comment: My version looks like: 0.22.6, not only one number. I forgot to add it to description. Already updated, sorry.