# How to sort the string based on numbers present in it, separated by (.)

Tags: javascript, sorting

Hi I want to sort the string based on numbers present in it
e.g

- 1.1.act2
- 13.1.2.1.act3
- 2.1.4.act56
- 1.3.actorg
- 3.1.3.args
- 13.1.3.4.acr

I want to this in a manner

- 1.1.act2
- 1.3.actorg
- 2.1.4.act56
- 3.1.3.args
- 13.1.2.1.act3
- 13.1.3.4.acry

How do I achieve it in javascript?

Comment: You can use answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number) to build a `compare` function for `array.sort()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Arrays` [`sort`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) method with a custom iterator function. e.g:

```
mylist = ["1.1.act2", "13.1.2.1.act3", "2.1.4.act56", "1.3.actorg", "3.1.3.args", "13.1.3.4.acr"];

mylist.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.split("."); b = b.split(".");
    var parts = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < parts; ++i) {
        var numA = parseInt(a[i]); var numB = parseInt(b[i]);
        if (numA != numB)
            return numA > numB;
    }
});
```

This is a stub and untested, but I guess you see where I'm heading

Answer (score -2):

Try this. This code is not optimized but it works

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
    var arr=new Array();
arr[0]="1.1.act2";
arr[1]="13.1.2.1.act3";
arr[2]="2.1.4.act56";
arr[3]="1.3.actorg";
arr[4]="3.1.3.args";
arr[5]="13.1.3.4.acr";

var it0=arr[0].split(".");
var it1=arr[1].split(".");
var it2=arr[2].split(".");
var it3=arr[3].split(".");
var it4=arr[4].split(".");
var it5=arr[5].split(".");

var newarr=new Array();
newarr[0]=parseInt(it0[0],10);
newarr[1]=parseInt(it1[0],10);
newarr[2]=parseInt(it2[0],10);
newarr[3]=parseInt(it3[0],10);
newarr[4]=parseInt(it4[0],10);
newarr[5]=parseInt(it5[0],10);

newarr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
alert(newarr);
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{

    if(newarr[i]==it0[0])
    {console.log(arr[0]);}
    else if(newarr[i]==it1[0])
    {console.log(arr[1]);}
    else if(newarr[i]==it2[0])
    {console.log(arr[2]);}
    else if(newarr[i]==it3[0])
    {console.log(arr[3]);}
    else if(newarr[i]==it4[0])
    {console.log(arr[4]);}
    else if(newarr[i]==it5[0])
    {console.log(arr[5]);}
    else if(newarr[i]==it6[0])
    {console.log(arr[6]);}
}
}
<input type="button" onclick="fnc()" value="click" />
```

Comment: This will only work for the first number, and only for 6 entries.

Comment: obviously it'll work for only 6 entries. I've shown the process.You shouldn't expect me to do the whole process. Copy and paste and see how it works. Its easier to vote negative without judging.

Comment: That is a non-generic solution. If you explicitness access each value, you can just sort them already by swapping them.

Comment: What do you mean by non generic solution.I works perfectly. what you need to do push the items into an array first. Have you tried my code? Try it and see in on firebug

Comment: @polin: I trust that your code works for the set of data given. But it is not generic in a sense, that you can use it on any kind of data following a specific scheme. Also the code is quite verbose for the task at hand. "*Its easier to vote negative without judging.*" - I did inspect your code quite thoroughly, be assured, but it simply lacks utility.

Comment: @polin: Also, it does possibly not provide correct results, as it only does take into account the *first* number the sequence, so there is no *strong* ordering of the elements. It may work for the few input strings at hand, but maybe not for another set of data.