# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Bottom white space in iOS 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ios7, worklight-runtime

[image: MyApp]

As you can see, at the bottom of my page remains a white space.
Its height is the same of the old status bar that was present in ios6.
Do i have to modify css? Because I never fixed an height for my app, worklight has always chosen the right size.

EDIT: you have to save the image and open in a desktop with different color to see the white space at the bottom.

```
*
 *  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 *  5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
 *  US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
 *  disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
 */

// This method is invoked after loading the main HTML and successful initialization of the Worklight runtime.
function wlEnvInit(){
    wlCommonInit();
    // Environment initialization code goes here
}

//Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert(device.version);
    if(device.version > "6.0")
        $(".elmecHeader").css("height", "70px");
}
```

Comment: I don't think I like the `device.version > "6.0"`, maybe look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight 6.0.0.1 was just released over the weekend; it addresses the status bar issue depicted in your screen shot.
The fix for 5.0.6.1 is not publically available (it is for customers who use this version and require it).

**Update:**
The white spacing at the bottom was a Worklight bug and is fixed in the latest 6.0.0.1 iFix as well as available for Worklight 6.0.0.x and Worklight 5.0.x for customers from IBM Fix Centeral.

Comment: Idan, thank for your response.
Just to be more clear, you said that my company whose is using WL 5.0.6.1 can request the fix for this issue?

Comment: If you are a customer, then it should be available to you via Passport Advantage; if you are a Business Partner, then it should be available to you via PartnerWorld. The white spacing issue at the bottom is still an open issue AFAIK, but you could check for a fix for it in the relevant website for you.

Comment: Thank you again Idan, can you confirm that this fixpack: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=hx6bfs&s=5#.UjxlfYbCXmY

correct the white space problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot verify this at this time (not at work...), but hey, go ahead and try. :)

Comment: Yes, that fix was included in the latest WL 5.0.6.1 interim fix for iOS7 described in this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to adjust your application for iOS 7.

You can use [Cordova Device API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device) to detect the OS that the app is running on and use different CSS for the different OS layout in iOS 6 and 7 (if you wish so).

I suggest to add more of the green background at the top, so that the new status bar in iOS 7 will not overlap with your app design.

This is a problem all web-based apps will suffer from in iOS until a proper solution is devised.

Be sure to also read the Apple-provided [iOS 7 Transition Guide](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/10/apple-publishes-ios-7-transition-guide-to-help-developers-adopt-flat-design/).

The above is one suggested approach; you should probably read more material about iOS 7 design and about how the status bar behaves in iOS 7 and choose the right path for your app.

- http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/
- http://www.slideshare.net/evgenybelyaev16/transition-guide

---

As for the bottom spacing, this is a bug in Worklight.

Comment: Thank you Idan. Can you see my original post edited? Is it correct to put that snippet of code in that js inside the iphone folder?

Comment: I would put it in common\yourapp.js >> wlCommonInit, and w/out the event listener.

Comment: I increased the height of my header of 20px, but what i figured out is that the white space is still there and the higher header will steal space to content. I tried to increment the body without success. May header and footer are jquerymobile-fixed.

Comment: See my edited answer with links to questions regarding spacing at the footer in apps using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: If those questions didn't help please create a minimized test case  exhibiting the spacing and provide either source code or zip file containing the Worklight project.

Comment: Hi Idan, sorry for the late.
Here's a link to a simple application with a red background that in ios7 show a white space at the bottom.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4195013/prova-1.0-iphone.zip

Comment: Did you first try to resolve the issue by looking at the jQuery-specific questions? Once I install Xcode 5 I'll be able to test this.

Comment: Hi Idan, 
have you had time to try this on Xcode5?
because I cannot find any solution about this on the jquery section! :(

Comment: I have not, but I do not believe this has got anything to do with Xcode, but with your CSS.

Comment: I am referring of course to jQuery Mobile's supplied CSS rather than Worklight. Maybe there are articles about it in jQuery's website?

Comment: @user1758494, I stand corrected - the white spacing issue is a bug in Worklight; we're on it.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight was updated since you posted your question.

Download the latest version of fixpacks, and make sure to read the tech note entirely: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574