# Worklight 6.0.0.1 & iOS 7 - White bar along bottom of screen?

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been working with Worklight 6.0.0.1 and I have noticed an issue with a white bar along the bottom of the screen in all Worklight apps running on iOS 7. I know this has been mentioned before with users of Worklight and iOS 7 ([IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Bottom white space in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533271/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-bottom-white-space-in-ios-7/18533649)) but the suggestion (upgrading to 6.0.0.1) by Idan Adar in that thread does not resolve the problem.

Is this a known issue or is there some additional configuration that needs to be done when working with iOS 7?

Just to be specific, under "About Eclipse" the version of IBM Worklight Studio is: 6.0.0.201309091542

Thank you,
Chris

Edited to add: I am using IBM Worklight Enterprise Edition. The links to update/install are here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running the very latest fixpacks ( http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574 ). Note that you may need more than one fixes to install.

Also, make sure you backup and delete your "native" folder so that it can build it again.

Make sure to follow the tips indicated in the tech note (same link as above).

Comment: I followed the instructions at that link to get Worklight 6.0.0.1. I installed the most recent fixpack from the locations linked to on that page.

I tried the suggestion of deleting the native folder and rebuilding. This allows me to run an iOS 7 app using Worklight but does not address the problem with the white bar along the bottom.

I have reproduced this problem on a brand new project created using Worklight 6.0.0.1. The default view for a new project is just the name of the project on a blank grey screen. The white bar still exists in this scenario.

Comment: Are you using the Developer Edition or are you a customer? Note that there are more than 1 fixes to download to be iOS 7 compatible. You need both.

Comment: On my computer it says 6.0.0.20130917-1749 - so it seems your build is not the latest

Comment: I have updated my post to indicate the version. I am using the Enterprise edition. I have clicked both of the links "Install Version 6.0.0 Fix Pack 1" and "Install the latest interim fix".

Both links end up with me downloading the same file. 6.0.0-WL-StudioP2-FP0001.zip

Note that they are not two different versions of the same file; they have the same timestamp.

Comment: Then it seems there is a mistake in the download links! I'll let them know.

Comment: It seems there was a typo in the link. This should be fixed today. In the meantime, here is a direct link: http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/quickorder?parent=ibm~Other+software&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+Worklight+Enterprise+Edition&release=6.0.0.1&platform=All&function=all&source=fc

Comment: That was the problem. This fixpack takes care of the problem. Thanks!