# Worklight iOS7 #wl_ios7bar disappears after keyboard displayed

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to fix the white bar and overlay problem described in questions such as this:
[Worklight 6.0.0.1 & iOS 7 - White bar along bottom of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137360/worklight-6-0-0-1-ios-7-white-bar-along-bottom-of-screen)
and this:
[IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Bottom white space in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533271/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-bottom-white-space-in-ios-7/18533649)

My goal is to have the overlay displayed at the top with a white background and then display everything else underneath. I am able to achieve this thanks to the #wl_ios7bar, but the problem is once I pop up a keyboard, the #wl_ios7bar disappears. I've taken some screenshot below and I've added a red border (in css) around #wl_ios7bar to show it disappears.

I'm using Worklight version 6.0.0.20130926-1933 of the Worklight Eclipse plugin and this problem only occurs in iOS7. Any suggestions?
[image: before keyboard]

[image: during keyboard]

[image: after keyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

set showIOS7StatusBar to false and implement those functions shown in step 4 and it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I opted to change the Cordova class for this workaround. It's worked well so far. In CDVViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
    //Lower screen 20px on ios 7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, this solution does not quite work either. Once I bring up the keyboard, the top of my app is covered by the overlay and the white rectangle behind it.