# IBM Worklight 6.0 - White status bar appearing in iOS 7 Simulator

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an Worklight application, and when I build iPad environment in Xcode it is displayed with a white color status bar (Ideally it should be transparent and appear as an overlay over the app) as well as a white empty space appearing at the bottom of the app.

[image: White status bar appearing in iPad - iOS 7]

Environment details:

- XCode 5.0.2
- iPad - iOS 7.0.3 simulator
- Worklight 6.0.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "6.0.0.2". Please provide the FULL build number; You can find it in Eclipse > About.

Additionally, please follow this IBM tech note regarding iOS 7 support in Worklight 6.0.0.1: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

Duplicate of:

- [Worklight 6.0.0.1 & iOS 7 - White bar along bottom of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137360/worklight-6-0-0-1-ios-7-white-bar-along-bottom-of-screen)
- [IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Bottom white space in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533271/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-bottom-white-space-in-ios-7)

Comment: The build version i am using is 6.0.0.20130926-1933