# underscore sort by string that represent section number

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

```
[
 {name:"foo", value:"1", order:"1.1.12"},
 {name:"foo bar", value:"2", order:"2.10.1"},
 {name:"bar", value:"3", order:"1.11.5"},
 {name:"baz", value:"4", order:"2.6.2"},
 {name:"foo baz", value:"5", order:"1.3.10"}
]
```

How can i sort this list by `order` with the help of underscore.js (or without).
so i will end up with this:

```
[
 {name:"a", value:"1", order:"1.1.12"},
 {name:"a", value:"5", order:"1.3.10"},
 {name:"a", value:"3", order:"1.11.5"},
 {name:"a", value:"4", order:"2.6.2"},
 {name:"a", value:"2", order:"2.10.1"}  
]
```

It's worth mentioning that `order` could be any digit long for example it could be:

```
1.1
2
3.1.2.3
```

so the solution has to be generic as possiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the string into an array of numbers and compare the numbers on the same position until you find something different:

```
var arr = [
 {name:"foo", value:"1", order:"1.1.12"},
 {name:"foo bar", value:"2", order:"2.10.1"},
 {name:"bar", value:"3", order:"1.11.5"},
 {name:"baz", value:"4", order:"2.6.2"},
 {name:"foo baz", value:"5", order:"1.3.10"},  
 {name:"foo baz", value:"5", order:"1.3"},   
 {name:"foo baz", value:"5", order:"2"}
];


arr.sort(function(item1, item2){
  var split1 = item1.order.split('.');
  var split2 = item2.order.split('.');
  var length = Math.min(split1.length, split2.length);
  for (var i=0; i<length; i++){
    if (+split1[i] < +split2[i])
      return -1;
    if (+split1[i] > +split2[i])
      return 1;
  }
  return split1.length - split2.length;

});

console.log(arr);
```

PS: Pure JS solution, not using Underscore.

Comment: He wants to go n levels deep. The split 1, split 2 solution only goes 2 levels deep, right?

Comment: @ZekeAlexandreNierenberg no, this will work no matter how long the sequences are.

Comment: Out of curiousity here... What do the `+` signs do in the if statements?? Also, when you return -1 or 1 where is that returning too? And what does it do?

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` receives as parameter a user-created comparison function that gets called with pairs of items from the array. For each pair the function should return 0 if they are equal, any positive number if the first is bigger and any negative number if the first is smaller (-1 and 1 work well because they are easy to spot). The unary `+` operator converts the value to a number. Without it, the values would be strings and the comparison would not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [How to compare software version number using js? (only number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number)

<s>You're certainly going to have to split the order variable by "."</s>

```
_.map([...],function(item) { item = item.split('.'); return item;});
```

At that point you have a new problem which is just sorting by multiple values. I think you'd perhaps group by the 0th value of each order array, then sort by the next.

Ultimately you'll probably end up with a recursive solution... I'll start thinking of one to edit in here.