# jQuery version string comparison

Tags: jquery, string, comparison, version, intuit-partner-platform

I use the remote version of https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js.
I also use the 1.10.1 version of jQuery.

However, Intuit still loads the 1.6 version of jQuery, giving two jQuery versions to my app.
The issue seems to be relative to the following condition : **window.jQuery.fn.jquery < "1.4.2"**.
In my case, window.jQuery.fn.jquery equals to "1.10.1" and the string comparison will succeed...

Could you please fix that issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Julien Orain

Comment: you'll have to change the way the comparison happens, for example, making it convert 1.6.x to the numeric value 1.6, and 1.10.x to 1.10 so that you can compare them numerically. we can't fix it for you, you'll have to do it, or you'll have to ask the plugin author to do it.

Comment: I guess one temporary way of fixing it would be to do: `$.fn.jquery = "1.9";` before including intuit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6832721/475565