# JavaScript sorting of an array with mixed type values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array which needs to be numerically sorted in descending order:

```
var arr = ['5', '5.1', '5.1.4', '6.0.0', '500'];
```

The needed order is like follows:

```
500
6.0.0
5.1.4
5.1
5
```

However all the methods I've tried don't seem to give the needed result. An example of such a sort function which won't work with that kind of array:

```
arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return b - a});
```

Could anybody please give me a hint on how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: 5.1.4 and 6.0.0 are not valid and that will throw a syntax error

Comment: Why aren't they valid? In any case - I have that list which needs to be sorted, the validity of the values is not a case here.

Comment: @sahbeewah They are not valid numbers but valid strings. Obviously the OP wants to sort "numbers" of versions, TOC or something like that.

Comment: Because they weren't in strings before he edited it. It is still not well defined. Example: How does 5.1.4 compare with 5.14?

Comment: Think of those strings as version numbers. 5.14 is greater than 5.1.4.

Comment: Transform all elements so they all have 3 values separated by a dot. 500 became 500.0.0. Then, they have all the same format and it's easier to compare them.

Comment: If these are meant to be versions, then `500` doesn't make any sense. If the OP keeps with the same convention throughout -- where `500` should be `5.0.0` then a simple direct sort can be done on the array of string values: `arr.sort()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for the following solution is taken *entirely* from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832706/1249581) (all credits there!) but result is inverted to make the order descending (+ fixed minor bugs):

```
['5', '5.1', '5.1.4', '6.0.0', '500'].sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a === b) {
       return 0;
    }

    var a_components = a.split('.'),
        b_components = b.split('.'),
        len = Math.min(a_components.length, b_components.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (parseInt(a_components[i], 10) > parseInt(b_components[i], 10)) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (parseInt(a_components[i], 10) < parseInt(b_components[i], 10)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (a_components.length > b_components.length) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a_components.length < b_components.length) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

// >> ["500", "6.0.0", "5.1.4", "5.1", "5"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){

    //if they are equal, return 0
    if(a==b) return 0;

    //split version numbers and compare each one until we got one that differs
    var verA = a.split('.'), verB = b.split('.');
    for(var i=0;i<Math.max(verA.length, verB.length);i++) {
        //verA is shorter or equal, so we return 1
        if(verA[i]===undefined)
            return 1;
        //verB is shorter or equal, so we return -1
        if(verB[i]===undefined)
            return -1;

        //first encounter where the 2 are defined and are different
        if(verB[i]-verA[i]!=0)
            return verB[i]-verA[i];

        //in other situations they are equal, so we go to the next iteration
    }

});
```