# Sorting a HTML dropdown-menu with decimals correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using a dropdown-menu where the user can select an application version (e.g. `1.0.4.3-0001`) to get more information on this specific version. To let the user find the correct version faster I want to sort this dropdown-menu so that the latest version is on top and the lowest version (`1.0.0.0-0001`) is at the bottom. Because all versions are getting fetched from a server and new ones can appear every day, I cannot sort them by hand.

I tried various jQuery and JavaScript codes to sort it right, but none of the codes seem to work with decimals like application versions (because it thinks `1.0.2.0` is newer than `1.0.12.0` for example). Does anyone know how to work with such a specific case?

Just in case anyone wants to see the code I've tried so far (with 'version' being my dropdown):

```
$("#version").html($("#version option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}))
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [**How to compare software version number using js**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number)

Comment: Hm, all of the snippets posted there are just about comparing two specific versions, not sorting them the right way...

Comment: @Sorcer that's what the sort function does though, compares a to b

Comment: I agree with you that - in order to sort something - you have to compare something. But I have no clue on how to continue with the snippets that compare two specific versions. Any idea on that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the text to an array of values and comparing those.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46e23/1/).

Its contents are thus:

**Body**

```
<select>
    <option>1.0.2.0</option>
    <option>1.0.12.0</option>
    <option>0.1.2.3</option>
</select>
```

**Init javascript**

```
$('select option').sort(
    function (compA,compB)
    {
        var a = compA.text.split(/[.-]/).map(function(x){return parseFloat(x)});
        var b = compB.text.split(/[.-]/).map(function(x){return parseFloat(x)});

        var i;
        for (i=0; i < a.length && i < b.length; ++i)
        {
            if (a[i] < b[i])
                return -1;
            else if (a[i] > b[i])
                return 1;
        }

        if (a.length != b.length)
        {
            if (i == a.length)
                return -1;
            if (i == b.length)
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    })
.each(function(i,a){$('select').prepend(a)});
```

That `.each` at the bottom reverses the `.sort` result.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to push this topic, but something on my website has changed. The select options aren't loaded by PHP anymore, now they get inserted by jQuery (with `.appendTo()`). Unfortunately your script doesn't seem to work with jQuery inserted options, any idea on how to fix that? :)

Comment: I just found a fix myself. The problem is not that the select options were inserted by jQuery, I just tried to sort it too fast after letting jQuery inserting the options. So I just call the function to sort the versions about 250ms later, this works just fine.