# How to know if the user has recently updated their Chrome Extension so I can alert them

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

So I have an info button, and whenever the user updates the extension, a little red dot shows on the top right, indicating there is an alert (new updates).

[image][image]

How I am doing it now, is by setting a row in localStorage whenever they view the updates-- and if that row is not found then the button will have the red dot.

The problem is, this solution requires me, after every update, to alter a few lines every time I kick off an update, like this:

```
//1.1.2 was the last version
localStorage.removeItem("update-1.1.2");

...

if( localStorage.getItem("update-1.1.3") === null ) {
  //show button image with red dot
}
else {
  //show button image without red dot
}

...

$('#info').click(function() 
{
  localStorage.setItem("update-1.1.3", "YES");
  //swap the button image w/ red dot, with the same image w/o the red dot
});
```

As you can see, every time I update I have to change the "update-x.x.x" string in 3 locations.

So my 2 questions are:
 - Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe a way to determine if a user has updated the extension?
 - Is image swapping the best way to go about this?  Or should I have a red dot image and make that appear and disappear.  To me performance difference would seem to be small-- it comes down to whether or not swapping an entire image, or making another image hidden/not hidden is more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things that can help you, both provided by [`chrome.runtime` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime):

1. You can detect the first time the extension runs after an update:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( function(details) {
     switch(details.reason) {
       case "install":
         // First installation
         break;
       case "update":
         // First run after an update
         break;
     }
   });
   ```
2. Instead of hardcoding the version number, you can extract it from the manifest:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
   ```

That said, I think it's perfectly reasonable to update a few constants in the code when you have something to say to the user.

As for the red dot, you can try using a dynamically-constructed icon, by using `<canvas>` and `imageData` property when calling `setIcon`. Or, for simplicity, use a badge with `setBadgeText`.

Answer (score 0):

With some code changes and `chrome` apis you should be able to remove the manual constants updates completely. This code is untested and uses the answer from [how to compare software version number using js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832721/26406) to compare versions.

```
var previousVersion = localStorage.getItem('previousVersion') || "0";
var currentVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
var versionComparison = versionCompare(previousVersion, CurrentVersion);

if (previsouVersion === "0") {
    // new install
} else if (versionComparison == -1) {
    // version is upgraded
} else if (versionComparison == 0) {
    // version is the same
}
```