# comparing double decimals os version number eg. (more than 10.11.2)

Tags: javascript

I'm using UAParser to get the OS version the user has, for example:

```
function osCheck() {
  var parser = new UAParser();

  return {
    name: parser.getOS().name,
    version: parser.getOS().version
  }
}
```

This gives me back `10.11.3` for example:
var osVersion = osCheck().version;

I then want to add a conditional to check whether is more than `10.11` taking into account the variable could have double decimals like `10.11.3` what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Slice after 5 characters? If there's a part behind 10.11, you know there's another version number, so it's automatically higher than 10.11 (eg 10.11.1) And then you can just split on the dots, parse the integer of the last part and compare integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a third party, try [semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver)

Then you can just:

```
const semver = require('semver')

semver.gt(version, '10.11.0')
```