# javascript - filter array of strings based on seperated ending

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of strings like this:

```
const strings = [
  "author:app:1.0.0",
  "author:app:1.0.1",
  "author:app2:1.0.0",
  "author:app2:1.0.2",
  "author:app3:1.0.1"
];
```

And I want to filter them so that only the ones that have the latest versions for the given "author:name" are left, thus removing ones that are not the latest (i.e. the "1.0.1" ones).

My expected result is this:

```
const filteredStrings = [
  "author:app:1.0.1",
  "author:app2:1.0.2",
  "author:app3:1.0.1"
];
```

Any way to do this simply?

Comment: Sorting means ordering, you're asking about filtering.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the result you expect to get

Comment: Make an object whose keys are the `author:name` strings. Loop through the array, checking whether the current version string is higher than the one already in the object for that key. If it is, replace the value. When you're done you'll have the highest version for each key.

Comment: I updated my post, tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two loops first one find new ones second one check which is bigger

```js
const strings = [
  "author:app:1.0.0",
  "author:app:1.0.1",
  "author:app2:1.0.0",
  "author:app2:1.0.2",
  "author:app3:1.0.1"
];
filteredones = [];
strings.forEach(element => {
  var arr = element.split(":");
  var isnew = true;
  var found = filteredones.find(function(element2) {
    var x = element2.split(":");
    return x[1] == arr[1] && x[0] == arr[0]
  });
  if (found == undefined) {
    filteredones.push(element);
  }
});
for (var i = 0; i < filteredones.length; i++) {
  element = filteredones[i];
  var arr = element.split(":");
  var isnew = true;
  var found = strings.find(function(element2) {
    var x = element2.split(":");
    return x[1] == arr[1] && x[0] == arr[0] && x[2] > arr[2]
  });
  if (found != undefined) {
    filteredones[i] = found;
  }
};

console.log(filteredones);
```

Comment: `x[2]> arr[2]` is a simplistic way of comparing versions, won't work all the time, for instance v1.11 vs v1.2. Also, you are declaring `isnew` but isn't using.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the value in the last index of the string in each of the elements of the array and if they qualify as a latest one put it to a new array.

Comment: This answer would be better if it was backed with an example.

Comment: And it would be even better with capital letters on the right words, and maybe a comma or two :)

Answer (score 0):

Build an object with `keys` as app name.

`getValue` method is calculate the version value so that to compare.

Update object value, when you see the version is recent (value is big).

```js
const strings = [
  "author:app:1.0.0",
  "author:app:1.0.1",
  "author:app2:1.0.0",
  "author:app2:1.0.2",
  "author:app3:1.0.1"
];

const filter = data => {
  const res = {};
  const getValue = item =>
    item
      .split(":")[2]
      .split(".")
      .reduceRight((acc, curr, i) => acc + curr * Math.pow(10, i), 0);
  data.forEach(item => {
    const app = item
      .split(":")
      .slice(0, 2)
      .join(":");
    if (!res[app] || (app in res && getValue(item) > getValue(res[app]))) {
      res[app] = item;
    }
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

console.log(filter(strings));
```

Comment: Instead of `>` should be `<`, it's keeping the smallest numbers. Also your code don't work if different authors have same app name. Also on it v1.11 > v2.0

Comment: @ariel, Good catch. I fixed both the issues. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to store the key/version pairs, and convert to appropriate output on the end. The version comparison can be any of those found here: [How to compare software version number using js? (only number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832596/how-to-compare-software-version-number-using-js-only-number)

```
result = {};
for (var s of input) {
  // parts = ["author", "appname", "version"]
  var parts = s.split(":");
  var i = parts[0] + ":" + parts[1];
  if (!result[i] || compareVersion(parts[2], result[i]))
    // If not present or version is greater
    result[i] = parts[2]; // Add to result
}
result = Object.keys(result).map(k => k + ":" + result[k])
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/bortao/pen/LYVmagK