# Measure jQuery plugin requirements

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a jQuery plugin but I don't know which version of jQuery is minimal for my plugin to run.

Is there any way to measure the requirements of my jQuery plugin ?

Comment: The OP is *developing* the plugin.

Comment: I guess you could do that empirically and try to run your plugin several times, each time downgrading jquery until it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is the only way to do it. At least what I know.

Comment: This might be informative: [Testing jQuery Plugins Cross-Version With Grunt](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/01/testing-jquery-plugins-cross-version-with-grunt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

I haven't used this but a quick search turned up [$versions](https://github.com/protonet/jquery-versions) which claims to be an easy way of testing your plugin against multiple versions of jQuery.

If you have a page with the tests/demos you need to check, you could always put that code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and run down the list of versions of jQuery in the Frameworks & Extensions menu.