# How to tell if jquery version is greater than 1.7?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that `jQuery.fn.jquery` gives me `1.10.2`, and I want to use `.on` binding for anything at least jQuery version `1.7`.

What I'm doing is:

```
var jQueryFloat = parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery); // 1.1
if (jQueryFloat >= 1.7) {
  // do jQuery 1.7 and above specific code
}
```

1.1 is less than 1.7, so my jQuery 1.7 and above code does not get run.

Any ideas on another way to figure out if my current version of jQuery is greater than or equal to `1.7`? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-if-jquery-is-loaded-and-what-version

Comment: Not a duplicate... if you read the question it is different.  The asker knows how to get the jQuery version.

Comment: @OP, Why wouldn't it be a good way for you?

Comment: [Checking the jquery version using a regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073423/jquery-plugin-check-version)

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of this, but why not split the version along the decimal and check both the major is greater than or equal to 1 and the minor version is greater than or equal to 7.

Comment: If you need backwards compatibility, I recommend branching the project and then making the necessary changes. Otherwise, I wouldn't recommend bothering to support older versions of jQuery.

Comment: You should really use feature detection, rather than trying to parse the version. Check if $.fn.on is truth-y (see my answer below)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are just looking to use `.on()` if possible, then don't try and parse the version - use feature detection.

```
var iCanUseOn = !!$.fn.on;

if(iCanUseOn) {

} else {

}
```

If you want to use more than just `.on()`, then that's fine, too. Come up with flags for each feature you want to use, but parsing the version is not a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use as below.

```
var arr = $.fn.jquery.split('.'); //["1", "10", "2"]

if(arr[0] > 1 || (arr[0] == 1 && arr[1] > 7))
{
    //Do your thing
}
```

The above condition will work for future versions like 2.0.1 etc.

Comment: This is correct, though I would also check the major version (in case someone upgrades to 2.0/2.1 etc)